# Is conditional expectation same for all periods for stationary process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, signal-processing, stationary-processes

Suppose there is a stationary process Y(t)

I know that E[Y(t)]=E[Y(t-k)]  must hold for any k.

But does

```
E[Y(t)|Y(t-1)] = E[Y(t-1)|Y(t-2)]
```

necessarily hold?

Not sure if the conditional distribution, so that conditional expectation, is the same across time.

Comment: "But does E[Y(t)|Y(t-1)] = E[Y(t-1)|Y(t-2)] necessarily hold?" No, what happens is that E[Y(t)|Y(t-1)] = g(Y(t-1)) and E[Y(t-1)|Y(t-2)] = g(Y(t-2)) for the same function g.